# AS3 if or removeChild not working

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, removechild

For start I have to say that adding - removing child in AS3 is something new to me...

I have managed to add anything I want but the problem is that when a new result occur the previous has to disappear and the new will display in the same spot. Well the problem is here. They appear producting childs one over the other. Here is the code where i tried to removeChild using an if

```
//--------------------------μεταβλητές-----------------------------
var iStr:String;
var iffpD:String;
var iRankP:String;
var iq0:Number;
var iq1:String;
var iq2:String;
var iq3:String;
var iq4:String;
var iq5:String;
var iq6:String;
var iq7:String;
var iFree:String;
var iclimc:String;
var ishootr:String;
var ispecialf:String;
var Ranked:Number;
var i:Number;
var day:Number;
var Powered:Number;
var PPD:Number;
var RankN:Array = new Array(0);
var rankupday:Array = new Array(0);
var rankpointup:Array = new Array(0);
var apotelesma:Number;
var oloioibathmoi:Array = new Array(P0,P1,P2,P3,CO0,CO1,CO2,CO3,S0,S1,S2,S3,L0,L1,L2,L3,CPT0,CPT1,CPT2,CPT3,M0,M1,M2,M3,COM0,COM1,COM2,COM3,LC0,LC1,LC2,LC3,C0,C1,C2,C3,G0,G1,G2,G3,FM0,FM1,FM2,FM3,SM0,SM1,SM2,SM3,NF0,NF1,NF2,NF3,WCF0,WCF1,WCF2,WCF3,LF0,LF1,LF2,LF3,Gow0,Gow1,Gow2,Gow3)


//----------------------------restricts--------------------------------
Str.restrict = "0-9\\.";
ffpD.restrict = "0-9";
RankP.restrict = "0-9";
q1.restrict = "0-9";
q2.restrict = "0-9";
q3.restrict = "0-9";
q4.restrict = "0-9";
q5.restrict = "0-9";
q6.restrict = "0-9";
q7.restrict = "0-9";
Free.restrict = "1-3";
climc.restrict = "0-3";
shootr.restrict = "0-3";
specialf.restrict = "0-3";

//--------------------------borders--------------------------------------
Str.border = true;
ffpD.border = true;
RankP.border = true;
q1.border = true;
q2.border = true;
q3.border = true;
q4.border = true;
q5.border = true;
q6.border = true;
q7.border = true;
Free.border = true;
climc.border = true;
shootr.border = true;
specialf.border = true;

//--------------------i = noti.text-------------------------------------

iStr= Str.text;
iffpD= ffpD.text;
iRankP= RankP.text;
iq1= q1.text;
iq2= q2.text;
iq3= q3.text;
iq4= q4.text;
iq5= q5.text;
iq6= q6.text;
iq7= q7.text;
iFree= Free.text;
iclimc= climc.text;
ishootr= shootr.text;
ispecialf= specialf.text;
day = 0
i = 0
apotelesma = 0
//---------------------button------------------------------------------

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Calco);

function Calco(event:MouseEvent):void
{

        **if(bathmos1 && bathmos1.parent)
        {
            bathmos1.parent.removeChild(bathmos1);
            bathmos1 = null;
        }


        if(bathmos0 && bathmos0.parent)
        {
            bathmos0.parent.removeChild(bathmos0);
            bathmos0 = null;
        }


        if(bathmos2 && bathmos2.parent)
        {
            bathmos2.parent.removeChild(bathmos2);
            bathmos2 = null;
        }**



    iStr= Str.text;
    iffpD= ffpD.text;
    iRankP= RankP.text;

    iq1= q1.text;
    iq2= q2.text;
    iq3= q3.text;
    iq4= q4.text;
    iq5= q5.text;
    iq6= q6.text;
    iq7= q7.text;
    iFree= Free.text;
    iclimc= climc.text;
    ishootr= shootr.text;
    ispecialf= specialf.text;
    Ranked = Number(RankP); 

    Powered = Number(iStr);
    PPD = (Number(iFree) * 5) + (Number(iclimc) * 5/2) + (Number(ishootr) * 5) + (Number(ispecialf) * 10) + (9 / 5)
    //------------------------------------------rank finder RankN--------------------------------
    if (Number(iRankP) < 15) {
        RankN[0] = "1"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 45) {
        RankN[0] = "2"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 80 ) {
        RankN[0] = "3"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 120 ) {
        RankN[0] = "4"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 170 ) {
        RankN[0] = "5"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 250 ) {
        RankN[0] = "6" 
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 350 ) {
        RankN[0] = "7"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 450 ) {
        RankN[0] = "8"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 600 ) {
        RankN[0] = "9"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 800 ) {
        RankN[0] = "10"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "11" 
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1400 ) {
        RankN[0] = "12" 
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1850 ) {
        RankN[0] = "13"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 2350 ) {
        RankN[0] = "14"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "15"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3750 ) {
        RankN[0] = "16"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 5000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "17"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 6500 ) {
        RankN[0] = "18"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 9000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "19"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 12000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "20"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 15500 ) {
        RankN[0] = "21"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 20000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "22"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 25000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "23"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 31000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "24"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 40000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "25"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 52000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "26"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 67000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "27"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 85000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "28"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 110000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "29"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 140000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "30"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 180000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "31"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 225000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "32"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 285000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "33"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 355000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "34"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 435000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "35"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 540000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "36"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 660000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "37"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 800000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "38"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 950000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "39"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1140000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "40"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1350000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "41"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1600000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "42"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1875000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "43"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 2185000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "44"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 2550000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "45"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "46"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3500000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "47"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 4150000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "48"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 4900000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "49"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 5800000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "50"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 7000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "51"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 9000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "52"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 11500000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "53"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 14500000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "54"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 18000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "55"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 22000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "56"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 26500000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "57"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 31500000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "58"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 37000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "59"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 43000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "60"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 50000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "61"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 100000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "62"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 200000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "63"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 500000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "64"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) > 500000000 ) {
        RankN[0] = "65"
    }



    ertext.text = ""
    iq0 = Number(iffpD) - Number(iq1)-Number(iq2) -Number(iq3)-Number(iq4)-Number(iq5)-Number(iq6)-Number(iq7)
    if (Number(iStr) == 0 || Number(iffpD) >= 250 || Number(iffpD) == 0 || iq0 < 0 ) {
        ertext.text = "Fill Strenght, FFs per day, rank points!"
    } else {

        //while (RankN[day] != "65"){
        while (Number(iRankP) < 500000000){
            if (Number(iRankP) < 15) {
        RankN[day] = "1"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 45) {
        RankN[day] = "2"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 80 ) {
        RankN[day] = "3"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 120 ) {
        RankN[day] = "4"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 170 ) {
        RankN[day] = "5"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 250 ) {
        RankN[day] = "6" 
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 350 ) {
        RankN[day] = "7"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 450 ) {
        RankN[day] = "8"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 600 ) {
        RankN[day] = "9"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 800 ) {
        RankN[day] = "10"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "11" 
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1400 ) {
        RankN[day] = "12" 
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1850 ) {
        RankN[day] = "13"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 2350 ) {
        RankN[day] = "14"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "15"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3750 ) {
        RankN[day] = "16"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 5000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "17"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 6500 ) {
        RankN[day] = "18"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 9000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "19"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 12000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "20"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 15500 ) {
        RankN[day] = "21"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 20000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "22"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 25000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "23"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 31000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "24"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 40000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "25"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 52000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "26"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 67000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "27"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 85000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "28"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 110000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "29"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 140000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "30"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 180000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "31"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 225000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "32"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 285000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "33"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 355000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "34"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 435000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "35"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 540000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "36"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 660000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "37"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 800000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "38"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 950000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "39"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1140000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "40"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1350000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "41"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1600000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "42"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 1875000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "43"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 2185000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "44"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 2550000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "45"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "46"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 3500000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "47"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 4150000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "48"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 4900000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "49"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 5800000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "50"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 7000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "51"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 9000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "52"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 11500000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "53"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 14500000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "54"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 18000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "55"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 22000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "56"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 26500000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "57"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 31500000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "58"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 37000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "59"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 43000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "60"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 50000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "61"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 100000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "62"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 200000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "63"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) < 500000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "64"
    } else if (Number(iRankP) > 500000000 ) {
        RankN[day] = "65"
    }
            Powered = Powered + PPD
            apotelesma = ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 0/100)* iq0) +
                         ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 20/100)* Number(iq1)) +
                         ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 40/100)* Number(iq2)) +
                         ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 60/100)* Number(iq3)) +
                         ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 80/100)* Number(iq4)) +
                         ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 100/100)* Number(iq5)) +
                         ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 120/100)* Number(iq6)) +
                         ((((Number(RankN[day])-1)/20+(45/150))*((Powered/10)+40))* (1 + 200/100)* Number(iq7));

            apotelesma = apotelesma / 10;
            iRankP = String(Number(iRankP) + apotelesma);


            if (Number(RankN[day]) > Number(RankN[day - 1])) {
                rankupday[i] = String(day);
                rankpointup[i] = iRankP
                i ++
            }
            if (Number(RankN[day]) == 62 && Number(RankN[day-1]) == 61) {
                Gow.text = String(day);
            }
            day = day + 1
        }
    }
    rank1.text = rankupday[0];
    rank2.text = rankupday[1];
    rank3.text = rankupday[2];
    Goww.text = String(day);





    var bathmos0:MovieClip = new oloioibathmoi[RankN[rankupday[0]]-1];
    addChild(bathmos0);
    bathmos0.x = 60;
    bathmos0.y = 535;
    bathmos0.alpha=.5;
    var bathmos1:MovieClip = new oloioibathmoi[RankN[rankupday[1]]-1];
    addChild(bathmos1);
    bathmos1.x = 156;
    bathmos1.y = 535;
    bathmos1.alpha=.5;
    var bathmos2:MovieClip = new oloioibathmoi[RankN[rankupday[2]]-1];
    addChild(bathmos2);
    bathmos2.x = 256;
    bathmos2.y = 535;
    bathmos2.alpha=.5;


    day=0
}
```

It seems that "if" is not working... How can I check if there is something to remove or not...
I put the full code and the "if" is with ** at the start and at the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bathmos0:MovieClip = new oloioibathmoi[RankN[rankupday[0]]-1];
```

... this variable (bathmos0) is local to the scope of your function. It doesn't exist at the beginning of your function, when you try to remove it with:

```
if(bathmos0 && bathmos0.parent)
{
bathmos0.parent.removeChild(bathmos1);
bathmos0= null;
}
```

If you want to remove the clip, give it a name:

```
var bathmos0:MovieClip = new oloioibathmoi[RankN[rankupday[0]]-1];
bathmos0.name = "bathmos0";
```

... and then remove it by name:

```
var mc:MovieClip = getChildByName("bathmos0");
if(mc && mc.parent)
{
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
    mc= null;
}
```

Either that, or put your `bathmosN` variables outside your function, so they are in scope when you try to remove them.

Comment: That's it! The last one! I putted the bathmosN variables outside the function and it worked pretty fine!!! Thanks a lot to everyone! I learned a lot from everyone!!!

Answer (score 2):

I usually have a function like so:

```
private function remove(child:DisplayObject):void
{
    if(child && child.parent)
    {
         child.parent.removeChild(child);
         child = null;
    }
}
```

As you can see it checks that the child exists (not null), then if it has a parent, and the parent contains the child on display list, if so it removes it and then nulls it, you may or may not want the child null, that's your choice.

Comment: I think this is a good approach. But it feels like `child.parent.contains(child)` is redundant, I can't see this ever returning false.

Comment: @strille - I wrote this from memory, good spot, i've updated it

Comment: I am not familiar with the "private" you use... I tried to use the if statement, i dont see any error to occur but it doesn't work... It seems to continue to stack the childs... There must be somewhere else a problem or I am such a noobie that I dont understant...

Comment: check out now and try to figure it out... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't if(child && child.parent) going to throw an error if child is null - because it will still try to evaluate child.parent to complete the expression? I have a similar method, but it checks for child.parent inside a check to see if child is null.

Comment: NO that's not how && works, it will evaluate the first part and if that's not true it will move on.

Comment: I'm mixing C# with AS, then. Most languages would throw an exception. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error? What do you mean 'not working'? And to remove child you have to check more than one condition. Try this:

```
if(bathmos1 != null && bathmos1.parent != null && stage.contains(bathmos1)){
  stage.removeChild(bathmos1);
}else
    trace("bathmos1 is not null: " + bathmos1 != null);
    trace("bathmos1's parent is not null: " + bathmos1.parent != null);
    trace("stage contains bathmos1: " + stage.contains(bathmos1));
}
```

Comment: no errors at all.
the if statement is not used when there is something on stage...
also using the if you gave is not working...

Comment: .I get this now
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: It means that something is null :) I think that bathmos1 is null. Just try to trace it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little clearer if you nest your conditions, checking if your target MovieClip is null **before** you check if its parent is null.

This code cannot logically throw a null exception error:

```
if(bathmos1 != null)
{
    trace("bathmos1 is not null");
    if(bathmos1.parent != null)
    {
        trace("bathmos1 parent is not null");
        bathmos1.parent.removeChild(bathmos1);
    }
    bathmos1 = null;
}
```

So, to borrow from Neil, your reusable function would be:

```
private function removeIfExists($child:DisplayObject):void
{
    if($child)
    {
        if($child.parent)
        {
            $child.parent.removeChild($child);
        }
        $child= null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this one too. No error but it still stacking the childs... I dont understand...