# AS3 KeyboardEvent with an "if" giving errors

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

1st time using an EventListener for a KeyboardEvent and I cant make it work:

Here is the code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, Cal);

function Cal(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
        Calco();
    }
}
```

The errors I get are:

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 95  1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.

line 94 is the if line and 95 the Calco thing...
I dont get where is the problem. I have another sample of code that works fine and I used it as an example.

Comment: and sounds like Calco is expecting an argument which you are not passing in.

Comment: Argument meaning that i have to place something in bracets?

Comment: you can see Calco function here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075417/as3-if-or-removechild-not-working

Comment: e.keyCode is not the same as event.keyCode; you did not declared e. ?!?!? watch your code

Comment: Being a newbie I cant help it, I make many mistakes... Also Calco is a MouseEvent function... Can I use it?

Comment: you can use the MouseEvent function if the trigger for that function you want to be a mouse event, and not keyboard event.

Comment: I think I finally found a way to make it work! Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts... and working example:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


// #1 - use the proper variables / function  names, upper and lower cases:
// Classes: Xxxxxx
// function : xxxxxx, xxxXxxxx
// variables : xxxxXxxx, xxxxx
// constants : XXXXXX
// #2 - use the readable function name, no shotcuts... ( just few advices );

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyboardDown);

function handleKeyboardDown(    e   :KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // #3 - for keyboard events use switch instead...

    // The error which was here is that the variable which parsed is named 'event' and you are using 'e',
    // you need to use the same name as it being initialized
    switch(e)
    {
        case Keyboard.ENTER :

            // the error for your 'Calco()' function, is because
            // function Calco (value.... expects for an variable.
                    // in this case this function does not required any variables
            calculate();
            break;
    }
}

function calculate():void
{
    trace (this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the advice!!! I have a Calco function and it doesnt need to give a value or anything...